# Code hosting platform that allows sharing through link

Tags: thesis, code

I am finishing my thesis (Physics) and need to add a link to all the codes I created to do the analysis presented in the manuscript.

The codes are not polished and they are intended to be public eventually but not just yet. So I need a platform that will allow me to have a private project that can be seen through a link for the review committee and for other students to see only. Github and GitLab do not offer this and can't find a webpage that does.

There are a lot of codes and they are separated by folders to distinguish the different areas in which they were used. So whatever webpage needs to be able to have a similar structure than GitHub.

Does anyone know where I could find this sort of feature? Thanks!

PD: If you know of the appropriate tags to use in this question I would appreciate you letting me know which ones those are.

Comment: [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) offers private repositories for free. It's very similar to Github. (Note that in order to see the repository, viewers will need to create an account and be authorized by you -- I don't know of a site that allows sharing the code via a link alonw.)

Comment: Dropbox? I don't think this is question is about academia.

Comment: Dropbox doesn't allow a preview of all types of code because it doesn't recognize all of the extensions, but it sounds like the better option so far. You are right, the question is probably not the most adequate here but it's the one place I thought people might know. I don't know to which other community it could be transferred to have a better fit.

Comment: It might fit better on StackOverflow but I'm not sure

Answer (score 3):

### Option 1

Based on your requirements, it doesn't seem that you need the code to be directly accessible from a browser. So the traditional solution would be to create an archive (e.g. zip file) protected by a password, and make this file accessible for instance through your institution website or Google Drive, Dropbox etc. Then you give the link and the password to whoever you want and they can download and browse it on their own computer.

- Pro: protected and accessible through link
- Cons: not accessible from a browser

### Option 2

As an academic, you can have [private Github repositories for free](https://help.github.com/en/articles/applying-for-an-educator-or-researcher-discount) (probably also on other platforms). The people who need to access your code will need to have an account themselves, and you will have to explicitly grant access to them in the Github interface.

- Pro: protected and accessible from a browser
- Cons: requires people to create an account if they don't have one already

### Option 3

Since your code is meant to be made public eventually, you could simply create a public repository and give the link to the people who need to access it. It doesn't really matter that the code is not polished or even finished, Github and other platforms are designed for projects under active development anyway (and you can  mention "work in progress" in the README file to make this clear). Additionally it's quite unlikely that anybody would find your code among the millions of repositories, unless you advertise it in a paper or webpage.

- Pro: accessible from a browser, no need for an account
- Cons: accessible to anyone who finds it

### Option 4

I hesitated mentioning this one since it's kind of hacky, but for the sake of completeness: [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) is a platform meant for sharing Latex documents. Like github, it is backed by git, so as far as I know you can actually create a directory structure and push any file there. Then you can share the repository as a link, which contains a long random key so it's impossible for somebody to find it by chance.

- Pro: private, accessible from a link, no account required for people to access it
- Cons: kind of a hack

Comment: Small remark re option 2: Github now allows free private repositories for all users: https://techcrunch.com/2019/01/07/github-free-users-now-get-unlimited-private-repositories/

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to share a single file of code, and the file directory of the project does not matter, www.pastebin.com allows you to publish text files onto the Internet and share them with people by giving them links.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. It accomplishes the task the OP asked for, and nobody else mentioned it.

Comment: I downvoted, because it is no good solution. Most pastebin services are not private at all, they are only useful for shorter snippets, but not for whole repositories (The question explicitly says: "So whatever webpage needs to be able to have a *similar structure than GitHub*."), usually nobody will give you any guarantees for availability (i.e. they may delete it any time) and you advocate one particular service, went is unclear why you recommend this one (there are literally hundreds of such public pastebins). So it does *not* accomplish the task, because it has no "GitHub structure".

Comment: I’m not familiar with any other pastebin services, but two of the options you choose when you’re posting something on pastebin.com are the amount of time before your post will expire (by default, “never”) and whether or not you want to make it public. It only handles one file at a time, but other than that, it meets all of the OPs criteria.